# UI access problems when passing a String between Activities

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

This is android studio. I can't figure out why I am unable to open SelectPlayer.java and SelectPlayer2.java from my MainActivity.java class using buttons. It has something to do with the way I am using intent String data = i.getStringExtra("text_key"); to retrieve the String from my AddPLayer.java class I believe. I am able to populate the listview using Edittext, but then the buttons in MainActivity will not open my SelectPlayer and SelectPlayer2 activities. Please help.

MainActivity UI to create buttons for navigating to 5 menus

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        //Declare variables
        Button gameStart;
        Button addPlayer;
        Button selectPlayer1;
        Button selectPlayer2;

        //Create OnCLickListener for buttons
        View.OnClickListener listener1 = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //Use listener with switch case scenarios to navigate to different UIs
            listener1 = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch(v.getId()){
                        case R.id.startgame:
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GameEmulator.class));
                            break;
                        case R.id.addplayerbutton:
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddPlayer.class));
                            break;
                        case R.id.selectplayer1:
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SelectPlayer.class));
                            break;
                        case R.id.selectplayer2:
                             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SelectPlayer2.class));
                    }
                }
            };
            //Setting content to id buttons and set listeners
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            gameStart= findViewById(R.id.startgame);
            gameStart.setOnClickListener(listener1);
            addPlayer= findViewById(R.id.addplayerbutton);
            addPlayer.setOnClickListener(listener1);
            selectPlayer1= findViewById(R.id.selectplayer1);
            selectPlayer1.setOnClickListener(listener1);
            selectPlayer2= findViewById(R.id.selectplayer2);
            selectPlayer2.setOnClickListener(listener1);
        }
    }
```

Addplayer class to add players using intent to separate activities

```
    public class AddPlayer extends Activity{

        //Declare buttons and edittext
        Button listButtonplayer1;
        Button listButtonplayer2;
        EditText playerIn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.playerinput);


            //Identify buttons and editext
            playerIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputname);

            listButtonplayer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
            listButtonplayer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    //Using intent to send input to SelectPLayer Class

                    Intent i = new Intent(AddPlayer.this,SelectPlayer.class);



                    //Using string text_key to get and send string through intent
                    i.putExtra("text_key", playerIn.getText().toString());

                    //Start intent activity
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            //Second button I am trying to use for SelectPLayer2 activity only.
            listButtonplayer2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbutton2);
            listButtonplayer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //Using intent to send input to SelectPLayer2 Class
                    Intent in = new Intent(AddPlayer.this, SelectPlayer2.class);


                    in.putExtra("text_key", playerIn.getText().toString());

                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Class to select player 1

```
    public class SelectPlayer extends Activity {   

        //Public static array list with adapter to crete the array and reference for listview being sent by intent from AddPLayer class
        public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        public static ListView selectView;
        TextView title;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.selectplayer);

            //Identify selectview ListView
            selectView = findViewById(R.id.selectview);
            selectView.setClickable(true);
            selectView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Using adapter for ListView menu
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
            selectView.setAdapter(adapter);
            selectView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); // finding the item which has been clicked by the user
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SelectPlayer.this, GameEmulator.class); //starting an intent to call GameEmulator Activity
                    intent.putExtra(GameEmulator.value, item);// Putting the value clicked by user in intent
                    startActivity(intent); // starting GameEmulator Activity
                }
            });
            //Using intent to retrieve string from AddPlayer Activity
            Intent i = getIntent();
            String data = i.getStringExtra("text_key");
            list.add(data);
            changeList();
        }
        public  void changeList()
        {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Class to select player 2

```
    public class SelectPlayer2 extends Activity {

        //Public static array list with adapter to crete the array and reference for listview being sent by intent from AddPLayer class
        public static ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;

        Intent in;
        ListView selectView2;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.selectplayer2);

            selectView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.selectview1);
            selectView2.setClickable(true);
            selectView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Using adapter for ListView menu
            adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list1);
            selectView2.setAdapter(adapter1);
            selectView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        String item =(String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); // finding the item which has been clicked by the user
                        Intent in = new Intent(SelectPlayer2.this, GameEmulator.class); //starting an intent to call GameEmulator Activity
                        in.putExtra(GameEmulator.value, item);// Putting the value clicked by user in intent
                        startActivity(in); // starting GameEmulator Activity

                }
            });
            //Using intent to retrieve string from AddPlayer Activity
            in = getIntent();
            String data = in.getStringExtra("text_key");
            list1.add(data);
            changeList();
        }
        public static void changeList()
        {

            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you click the `selectplayer1` and `selectplayer2` buttons from `MainActivity`?

Comment: The app shuts down and has to restart, The app will only let me access AddPLayer Activity from the MainAcitivty via my Buttons. When I try to access SelectPLayer or SelectPlayer2 from the home screen MainActivity the app shuts down. I am confused because AddPLayer is the only button working at the moment.

Comment: You need to pass the extra along with the intent in the `case` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have not called `intent.putExtra("text_key")` in any of the `case` statements in the listener. Hence, the `data` string in both `SelectPlayer`s is null.

Answer (score 0):

The reason my activity was not opening was because of my null pointer exception error. I had to use an if statement when using getIntent() function to specify what to do when the string was not null. For example:

```
 if(data != null){
            list.add(data);
        }
        if(data != ""){
            changeList();
        }
```